# Negative Index in sympy function cannot be displayed after sympify

Tags: python, sympy

I have a project where I need to display negative indices in my formula that I generate with inputs that are unknown before runtime so I have to call sympy.sympify() on these equations. However, this breaks the way it displays my indices.

It is not possible to sympify something like `k_{-1}`, but when declaring:

```
kN1 = sympy.symbols("k_{-1}")
sympy.preview(kN1)
```

I get the correct output with the negative integer.
[image: correct output]

Is there a way to keep this index throughout the sympify method or is it possible to restore this way displaying them after I used sympify and did all my calculations?

In shorter: Can I have a negative integer as index after calling:

```
a = "kN1"
expr = sympy.sympify(a)
```

I am using sympy 1.9 and python 3.8

Comment: Use `parse_expr` for parsing strings: `parse_expr('kN1', {'kN1': Symbol('k_{-1}')})`

Answer (score 1):

During sympification, the parser is not smart enough to recognize that something in braces after an underscore or "^" is a sub/superscript. So as you have found you won't be able to successfully sympify such an expression. If you use regular symbol names you can `xreplace` them with the desired names when you are ready to print:

```
...input and manipulation with kn1=Symbol('kn1') in expr
print(expr.xreplace({kn1:Symbol('k_{-1}')}))
```